# I am trying to my body behind the header also cause youtube videos to be responsive for mobile

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get the video to be responsive from the desktop to the mobile device. I am also trying to scroll the body behind the header.

```css
.embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

body {
  padding: 40px 10px 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header>





</header>

<p>
  More episodes in this series

</p>
<br/>


<p>

  HTML5 & CSS3 Fundamentals: Development for Absolute Beginners Creating Tables - 09 Creating Tables - 09 13:00
  <br>
  <br/>
</p>

<div class='embed-container'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed//iLEGE7k9FD4' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Use `z-index: 1000;` to the header to make the body scroll below it.

Comment: And where is your html?

Comment: It was my title but I removed it. Left html tag.. ops...

Comment: Also my video doesnt exspand in my desktop browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: Kindly put your html and css properly for us to see and help you. And for the header part you can use the above comment.

Comment: You need the video's width to be 100% not the max width.

Comment: thanks im new at this... ;  )

Comment: No worries. Am learning too. Tell me if that works and I will put it down as an answer.

Comment: have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/8zkunqxy/2/

Comment: I removed max- it didn't work..

Comment: Check the link, see if that's what you want.

Comment: thanks for jsfiddle

Comment: when using code in jsfiddle do i create a style.css file for index file? I'm a newbe to coding thanks  :  )

Comment: You don't need to create any files. Just copy and paste your original code in places as mentioned there. For ex your html should go where its marked html.

Comment: ok thanks.. You a blessing.. I'll work with the code on my cell later... :  )

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you face any trouble. Would love to help. Happy coding!